# Can't make bootable USB

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to create a bootable USB - I get the error message:

```
An error () occured while executing syslinux. Your USB drive won't be bootable.
```

I'm using the Universal USB installer 1.9.5.1 from Pendrive.
I've downloaded `ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso`

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: try unetbootin software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso)

Comment: Karel: This is a grandfather question. It is older than the "duplicated" question you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try another app like [this](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) for Windows, or [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unetbootin/) for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reformat the usb stick to FAT 32 from NTFS. This must be solution of your problem. If the problem still occur, you can try to disable firewall.

Comment: USBs were formatted for FAT 32 - Firewall had no effect

Comment: Then, i suggest you to use win32 disk imager. You can download here. http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/